# UIImage in NSManagedObject custom subclass w/o storing the thumbnail in the Core Data Model and avoiding jerky scrolling?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uicollectionview

**Nutshell:** What are ways to add a thumbnail `(UIImage *)` to a `NSManagedObject` custom subclass without storing the thumbnail in the Core Data Model and avoiding jerky scrolling in a `UICollectionView`?

I have a `UICollectionView` with Cells, each with a `UIImageView`.  I fetch objects from the `UICollectionViewController`.  In the `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method I assign the  `UIImageView` with an image from a `NSManagedObject`.  Originally I did this:

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:managedObject.image];
```

But when I scrolled the `UICollectionView` it was jerky (the images were too large).

I tried scaling them down within `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`, but that didn't help.  Finally I settled on this:

```
//in collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: in ViewController
IimageView.image = managedObject.thumbnail;

//in NSMangedObjects custom subclass .m
...
@property (nonatomic) UIImage *thumbnail;

//in NSMangedObjects custom subclass .m
...
-(id)initWithEntity:(NSEntityDescription *)entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
self = [super initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
if (self) {

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:self.image];
    CGSize sacleSize = CGSizeMake(190, 190);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sacleSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, sacleSize.width, sacleSize.height)];
    UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    thumbnail = smallImage;
}
return self;
```

}

The cells in my `UICollectionView` are (80 x 80).  With the above, my collection view scrolls nicely.  Performance wise, is it better to create a thumbnails in the `NSManagedObject` or should I instead do it somewhere else (but not in the `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method)?